# Wiki scraping using python

Tags: python, web, screen-scraping

I am trying to scrape the data stored in the table of this wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minister_of_Agriculture_(India).
However i am unable to scrape the full data
Hers's what i wrote so far:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
wiki = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minister_of_Agriculture_(India)"
header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'} #Needed to prevent 403 error on Wikipedia
req = urllib2.Request(wiki,headers=header)
page = urllib2.urlopen(req)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page,"html.parser")

name = ""
pic = ""
strt = ""
end = ""
pri = ""
x=""
table = soup.find("table", { "class" : "wikitable" })
for row in table.findAll("tr"):
    cells = row.findAll("td")

    if len(cells) == 8:
        name = cells[0].find(text=True)
        print name`
```

The output obtained is:
Jairamdas Daulatram, Surjit Singh Barnala, Rao Birendra Singh

Whereas the output should be: Jairamdas Daulatram followed by Panjabrao Deshmukh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you read the raw html?

Because some of the cells span several rows (e.g. Political Party), most rows do not have 8 cells in them.

You cannot therefore do `if len(cells) == 8` and expect it to work.  Think about what this line was meant to achieve.  If it was to ignore the header row then you could replace it with `if len(cells) > 0` because all the header cells are `<th>` tags (and therefore will not appear in your list).

**Page source (showing your problem):**

```
  <tr>
    <td><a href="/wiki/Jairamdas_Daulatram" title="Jairamdas Daulatram">Jairamdas Daulatram</a></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>1948</td>
    <td>1952</td>
    <td rowspan="6"><a href="/wiki/Indian_National_Congress" title="Indian National Congress">Indian National Congress</a></td>
    <td rowspan="6" bgcolor="#00BFFF" width="4px"></td>
    <td rowspan="3"><a href="/wiki/Jawaharlal_Nehru" title="Jawaharlal Nehru">Jawaharlal Nehru</a></td>
    <td><sup id="cite_ref-1" class="reference"><a href="#cite_note-1"><span>[</span>1<span>]</span></a></sup></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="/wiki/Panjabrao_Deshmukh" title="Panjabrao Deshmukh">Panjabrao Deshmukh</a></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>1952</td>
    <td>1962</td>
    <td><sup id="cite_ref-2" class="reference"><a href="#cite_note-2"><span>[</span>2<span>]</span></a></sup></td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: In addition to telling him what he *can't* do, tell him what he *can* do. For example, he could replace `if len(cells) == 8` with `if len(cells) > 0`.

Answer (score 1):

Like already stated in a previous post. It does not make sense to set a static length. Just check if `<td>` exists. The code below is written in Python 3, but should work in Python 2.7 as well with some small adjustments.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

wiki = urlopen("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minister_of_Agriculture_(India)")

soup = BeautifulSoup(wiki, "html.parser")

table = soup.find("table", { "class" : "wikitable" })
for row in table.findAll("tr"):
    cells = row.findAll("td")

    if cells:
        name = cells[0].find(text=True)
        print(name)
```